# JQuery hide span outside of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide a span but having some trouble doing so. I want to get all the spans based on their ***for tag value*** and simply hide them. My question is, is it possible to get span's where there ***for tag*** equals something?

For example:

```
<input type="text" id="Address1" />
<span for="Address1" class="field-error">Boo</span>

<input type="text" id="Address2" />
<span for="Address2" class="field-error">Hoo</span>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c4UXb/6/)

JQUERY

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("span.field-error").hide();
});
```

Thanks in advance, DS.

Comment: You should be able to do something like `span[for="test"] { color:red; }` Though I don't think `for` on a `span` is valid, it should be on a `label`

Comment: The `for` attribute in a `span` tag is invalid HTML. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
$("span[for='Address1']").hide();
```

But it's not valid for span, instead you can use `data-` prefix for custom attributes, like

```
<span data-for="Address1">some text</span>
```

Then, `js` could be

```
$("span[data-for='Address1']").hide();
```

[An example.](http://jsfiddle.net/c4UXb/7/)